# Auto-regressive time series prediction

Tags: regression, time-series, self-study, forecasting

$\hat{x}_{t+1} = \beta_1x_t + \beta_2x_{t-1} + \dots \beta_Mx_{t-M+1}$

So we actually base our prediction on the previous $M$ values.

The task then specifies that we need to minimize the objective function:

$ J = \frac{1}{N-M}\sum\limits_{t=M}^{N-1}{(\hat{x}_{t+1}-x_{t+1})^2}$, which of course makes sense.

There is a further hint, however, that I don't understand. It suggests finding the matrix $A$ and the vector $b$ for which:

$J = \frac{||A\beta-b||^2}{N-M}$. Quote: "...this allows you to find the coefficients that minimize $J$. The final hint is to use the `scipy.linalg.toeplitz` function.

I haven't solved problems with time series before, so can you please elaborate a bit on the hints or link me to a book/article that could clarify things for me.

Thank you!

Comment: Consider adding a [tag:self-study] tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write each prediction in vector form:
$$\hat{x}_{t+1}=\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}x_t  \cdots x_{t-M+1} \end{bmatrix}}_{\mathbf{a}_{t,M}}\begin{bmatrix}\beta_1\\\vdots\\\beta_M\end{bmatrix}=\mathbf{a_{t,M}}\mathbf{\beta}$$
If you concatenate them vertically for each $t$, you'll obtain $A$, i.e. $$\begin{bmatrix}\hat{x}_{M+1} \\\vdots\\ \hat{x}_N\end{bmatrix}=\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{a}_{M,M}\\\vdots \\\mathbf{a}_{N-1,M}\end{bmatrix}}_A\mathbf{\beta}$$
The $b$ vector is the actual values. Differencing and taking the norm gives you the cost function, $J$.

Comment: Thank you! One more thing, looking at the definition of Toeplitz matrices, I still don't see how using one can be helpful in this case.

Comment: If you write the matrix $A$ explicitly, you’ll see that it is in toeplitz form. Solving linear systems involving toeplitz forms is computationally easier to solve.

Comment: When I wrote the matrix explicitly I saw that the rows of the matrix are just consecutive shifts to the right: $(1-2-3) \to (2-3-4)...$ (if $M = 3$, for example). So the property $a_{i,j} = a_{i-1,j-1}$ doesn't hold. Where am I wrong?

Comment: reverse the rows

Comment: Thanks. Silly of me not to have noticed :)